# Jquery iterate through multiple select options in a specific div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, loops

I want to iterate through multiple select options in a specific div via Jquery each function. And after that if there is atleast one empty field, the loop breaks and set 0 to `reqCourseFlag` variable.My implementation is below but it does not looping through

HTML:

```
 <div id="IENG349ReqCourses" class="reqCourses">
                                        <center>
                                            <table>
                                                <caption style="color:#f00;">Please select your grades for required courses.</caption>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td valign="middle">
                                                        <label>IENG 102 - Intro to IE:</label>
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <select id="intershipTypeBox" name="IENG102Grade">
                                                            <option value="">--select--</option>
                                                            <option value="NOT TAKEN">NOT TAKEN</option>
                                                            <option value="TAKING">TAKING</option>
                                                            <option value="A">A</option>
                                                            <option value="A-">A-</option>
                                                            <option value="B+">B+</option>
                                                            <option value="B">B</option>
                                                            <option value="B-">B-</option>
                                                            <option value="C+">C+</option>
                                                            <option value="C">C</option>
                                                            <option value="F">F</option>
                                                        </select>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td valign="middle">
                                                        <label>IENG104 - Comp. Aided Drawing:</label>
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <select id="intershipTypeBox" name="IENG104Grade">
                                                            <option value="">--select--</option>
                                                            <option value="NOT TAKEN">NOT TAKEN</option>
                                                            <option value="TAKING">TAKING</option>
                                                            <option value="A">A</option>
                                                            <option value="A-">A-</option>
                                                            <option value="B+">B+</option>
                                                            <option value="B">B</option>
                                                            <option value="B-">B-</option>
                                                            <option value="C+">C+</option>
                                                            <option value="C">C</option>
                                                            <option value="F">F</option>
                                                        </select>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td valign="middle">
                                                        <label>IENG 211 - Prob. In Eng.:</label>
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <select id="intershipTypeBox" name="IENG211Grade">
                                                            <option value="">--select--</option>
                                                            <option value="NOT TAKEN">NOT TAKEN</option>
                                                            <option value="TAKING">TAKING</option>
                                                            <option value="A">A</option>
                                                            <option value="A-">A-</option>
                                                            <option value="B+">B+</option>
                                                            <option value="B">B</option>
                                                            <option value="B-">B-</option>
                                                            <option value="C+">C+</option>
                                                            <option value="C">C</option>
                                                            <option value="F">F</option>
                                                        </select>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td valign="middle">
                                                        <label>IENG 212 - Eng. Statistics:</label>
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <select id="intershipTypeBox" name="IENG212Grade">
                                                            <option value="">--select--</option>
                                                            <option value="NOT TAKEN">NOT TAKEN</option>
                                                            <option value="TAKING">TAKING</option>
                                                            <option value="A">A</option>
                                                            <option value="A-">A-</option>
                                                            <option value="B+">B+</option>
                                                            <option value="B">B</option>
                                                            <option value="B-">B-</option>
                                                            <option value="C+">C+</option>
                                                            <option value="C">C</option>
                                                            <option value="F">F</option>
                                                        </select>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                                <tr>
                                                    <td valign="middle">
                                                        <label>IENG 221 - Work Syst. Analysis and Design:</label>
                                                    </td>
                                                    <td>
                                                        <select id="intershipTypeBox" name="IENG221Grade">
                                                            <option value="">--select--</option>
                                                            <option value="NOT TAKEN">NOT TAKEN</option>
                                                            <option value="TAKING">TAKING</option>
                                                            <option value="A">A</option>
                                                            <option value="A-">A-</option>
                                                            <option value="B+">B+</option>
                                                            <option value="B">B</option>
                                                            <option value="B-">B-</option>
                                                            <option value="C+">C+</option>
                                                            <option value="C">C</option>
                                                            <option value="F">F</option>
                                                        </select>
                                                    </td>
                                                </tr>
                                            </table>
                                        </center>
                                    </div>



   $('div.#IENG349ReqCourses: select> option:selected').each(function() {
        var value = $(this).val();

        if(value === ""){
            reqCourseFlag = 0;
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Any help would be appriciated.

Comment: Can you post what your html is?

Comment: Post an HTML example too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your selector is incorrect, you don't need the `.` or the `:`

```
  $('div#IENG349ReqCourses select> option:selected').each(function () {
```

demo http://jsfiddle.net/Xr5LL/